# How to get TOP X rows from Azure Table Storage using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I use **Get-AzTableRow** PowerShell Az command to get rows. 
How to get **TOP X** rows?

```
Get-AzTableRow -Table $cloudTable -CustomFilter $filter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks there is no built-in parameter like `-Top` for the `Get-AzTableRow` command, my workaround is to use the PowerShell pipeline to get the top X rows.

```
Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -customFilter $filter | Select-Object -First 2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This method **returns** only TOP X entries. But I'm not sure if it **receives** only TOP X from a table. Looks like pipeline receives all entries first and then filters. I have a huge number of rows in tables, some millions and really need to **receive** them portion by portion.

Comment: @MikaelChudinov Yes, it receives all entries first and then filters, because there is no built-in parameter like `-Top`, I think it is the only way to meet your requirement currently via `Get-AzTableRow`, or you can just call the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) manually via PowerShell, it supports `$top`, you could refer to this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41732682/9455659), it calls the create table api, the logic is similar. But I am also not sure the `$top` will `receive` them like you said.

Comment: Little Improvement: when you want to sort my RowId, you will encouter the behavior of Powershell, that sorting - for instance - Id "9" over "10". My workaround:

`Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RowKey | ForEach-Object { '{0:d10}' -f [int]$_ } | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this question (as I did), Get-AzTableRow now supports -Top (since [version 2.1.0 of AzTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzTable/2.1.0)).

From documentation:

```
-Top <Nullable`1>
    Return only the first n rows from the query (all parameter sets)
```